# Site hanging under IIS when calling through interop

Tags: permissions, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a website written using MVC3 where the backend is a 3rd party system written in Cobol.
The webserver should starts the Cobol runtime through an interop dll and thereafter performs a call to the relevant program.

When I run this setup from Visual Studio using IIS Express then everything works fine.
When I run it using "real" IIS5 however, the site hangs on the first call to the backend.
As far as running processes go, I can see that the runtime exe file is running meaning the
initial call was made and permissions seem to be ok.

I have tried setting all permissions for the user on both the involved directories
and files and also on the COM service.

What else could I be missing here? Is there any additional trace I could use?

Comment: Really IIS 5? What isolation level? Which process are you talking about, ASPNET_WP?

Comment: Yes, IIS on XP. Isolation level is 'medium' - but have tried the others too. The process is ASPNET_WP.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it from another forum - the backend was opening a debug window (trying) which wasn't visible.